# Unity Different behavior at rigidbody combined object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Why this two same objects show different behavior?

**objects**:

`one`: parent  Sphere1 (rigidbody use gravity) 
            -child  Cube1

`two`: parent  Cube2 (rigidbody use gravity) 
            -child  Sphere2

In this situation, I think that their center of mass is same position.
However object `one` is stable, on the other hand `two` is unstable(rolling down).

**this problem is solved**
this problem cased by script attached parent object.
To tell the truth, I've attached center of mass script to the both parent object.this script set center of mass at the center of object attached this one ,not the center of the two objects.  After removing the scripts, both objects fell down.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class centerOfMass : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 center;
    private Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    center = rb.centerOfMass;
}

void Update()
{
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.rotation * center);
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    center = rb.centerOfMass;
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position + transform.rotation * center, 0.08f);
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you include a screen of the components in the inspector, so we can safely assume that you've set it up correctly?

Comment: @Maakep thank you for your suggestion.  Sorry everyone, this problem caused by set center of mass script attached parents.

Comment: Edit original post if you want to add things to it! :) Code is very hard to read in comments. Also, be super-duper clear on what you wish to achieve and what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

When a  GameObject is a child of another one, the child will follow the parent. And if the parent is not in the ground and is affected by gravity, the parent will fall down to the ground and the child will follow.

In your cases:

- On the left the Sphere (the parent) is already in the ground so it
  will not move from there, and the box (the child) will not make any effect.
- On the right, it is the Box the parent and it is in the air, not in
  the ground, so it will until it touched the ground. The sphere will
  follow.

Comment: thank you your answer. this problem cased by my script attached parent object.

Comment: Ignacio has the right of it. in the inspector on of your objects is CUBE-Sphere, the other is SPHERE-Cube. in order for them to behave the same they must be the same. pick the object you want to imitate, left or right, then make the other object the same.

Comment: (drag Cube2 onto Sphere2) to make them both static, or (drag Sphere1 onto Cube1) to make them both roll.

Answer (score 0):

As my test, both of them fall.

Do you forget add a rigidbody on the first sphere?

[image]

Comment: thank you for two guys discussion.  this problem cased by my script attached parent object.

Comment: this is not THE answer but it is AN answer shingo hypothesized that adding a rigidbody would solve the problem. valid answer, though not correct.